# Extract the text of a label from an option Html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As I extract the text of a label from an option and put them in a json, they could help me, like this example:

```
<datalist id="datalist1">
<option value="US" label="United States" />
<option value="UK" label="United Kingdom" />
<option value="IN" label="India" />
</datalist>
```

and this is the code jquery:

```
$("#idDatalist option").each(function(idx, option) {
    var jsonPro = {};
    jsonPro.NOMBRE_PROVEEDORES = $(option).val();
    jsonPro.RUC_CEDULA = $(option).attr('label').text();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use the `text()` after the `attr()` function as it itself will give you the value of `label` attribute. Also push this JS object to an array to obtain the full result like below

```js
$(function() {
  var arr = []
  $("#datalist1 option").each(function(idx, option) {
    var jsonPro = {};
    jsonPro.NOMBRE_PROVEEDORES = $(option).val();
    jsonPro.RUC_CEDULA = $(option).attr('label');
    arr.push(jsonPro)
  }); 
  console.log(arr)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<datalist id="datalist1">
<option value="US" label="United States" />
<option value="UK" label="United Kingdom" />
<option value="IN" label="India" />
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you need an array of objects, otherwise jsonPro will always hold the last value

```
//Create an empty object
var jsonPro = [];
// check the id here and loop throught the options
$("#datalist1 option").each(function(idx, option) {
    // create a local object here
    var dataObj={}
    // populate the object with relevant value
    dataObj.NOMBRE_PROVEEDORES = $(option).val();
    // attr will give the value back. No need of text()
    dataObj.RUC_CEDULA = $(option).attr('label');
    // push this local object to the array
    jsonPro.push(dataObj)
}); 
console.log(jsonPro)
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/g450d7fq/1/)

Answer (score 1):

The `id` is mismatched and because the option's `label` attribute represents the value you do not need to use `text()`. Try the following:

```js
var arr = [];
$("#datalist1 option").each(function(idx, option) {
    var jsonPro = {};
    jsonPro.NOMBRE_PROVEEDORES = $(this).val();
    jsonPro.RUC_CEDULA = $(this).attr('label');
    arr.push(jsonPro);
});
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<datalist  id="datalist1">
  <option value="US" label="United States" />
  <option value="UK" label="United Kingdom" />
  <option value="IN" label="India" />
</datalist >
```